# Limit choices in field based on count of choice on the list

Tags: list, form

I have a sharepoint list tracking training dates for employees. Users add a new item, and select the training date they want from a choice field on the new item form.

Optimally, once a date is selected 10 times, that choice would not be available for other users to select. If that's not possible, a strikeout or verbiage would work as well.

Any thoughts? Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple solution. Usually a list showing the available date slots has worked for my purposes. There could be applied a filter for the list to exclude items which have the employee's name field already filled. This however doesn't prevent more advanced users from finding the list items filled by other users if they know where to look from.

Comment: Do you manually track the available date slots and remove choices when they are filled?

Comment: In the list view settings I can configure a filter based on the employee name field. The idea would be show only the list items where this field is still empty (i.e. not reserved), so I'd filter out the "non-empty ones". Then there would be no need for manual managing.